# Angular js - Round off

Tags: angularjs, math

Sorry if already asked by someone .
 how do i round off a decimal number . does angular js hav built in functions for that purpose

```
 $scope.roundoff_call=function()
            {   
                $scope.Math = window.Math;
                 $scope.abc =$scope.Math.round(0.19,4)  
            }
```

it gives output as 0 and not 0.2 .
Am new to angular js . Kindly Help Me

Comment: Why not simply round using plain old javascript?

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: angularjs didn't give the limit to put pure javascript in you're code.

Answer (score 3):

you can use angular existing filter

```
$filter('number')(number, 0)  in controller or service
```

or

```
<div>{{ val | number : 0}}</div>
```

Comment: filter does not change value . it only displays formatted number

Comment: yes filter will return the value and it will reflect in the view.  
if want to change the model value then we need to assign the returned value to the model.

Answer (score 2):

User html like

```
<span>{{val | number:0}}</span>
```

In `app.js`

```
<script>
  angular.module('numberFilterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 999.56789;
    }]);
</script>
```

Output

```
1000
```

Comment: filter does not change value. it only displays formatted number

Answer (score 0):

first, window.Math is not a angularjs function, is a javascript function.
Math.round() rounds a number to the nearest integer not a nearest real.

you can use this function to obtains the result you want

```
function my_rounded_number(number , decimal_places){
    x = number * window.Math.pow(10 , decimal_places)
    x = window.Math.round(x)
    return  x * window.Math.pow(10 , -decimal_places)
}

$scope.roundoff_call=function()
        {   
            $scope.Math = my_rounded_number;
            console.log("0.19");
             $scope.abc =$scope.Math.round(0.19,1)
            console.log($scope.abc);

        }
```

the result: 0.2